# Is using Order by in Outer query Mandatory?

Tags: sql, oracle, function, sql-order-by

I am curious to know that in the following query, do I need to use order by clause in outer query or not?

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT a1, b1, 
               row_number() over(ORDER BY A.b1 DESC) rNum
           FROM TABLE_A)
 WHERE rNum between 1 and 10 
***ORDER BY B1 DESC***
```

Comment: Nope you have already order the result by A.b1 so it wont be required.

Comment: @AjithSasidharan you ordered row_number's window, not the result set

Comment: @beherenow, so there might be chances of getting records in other order than B1 desc, if we DO not use Order by b1 desc in outer query and why?

Comment: @AjithSasidharan, as per my unerstanding /@beherenow is saying right. Subquery's order by is ordered row numbers window only not the outer query resultset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes use order by if you want the final 10 rows ordered by b1. as anything else is not guaranteed (it may happen for the example that its always in order, but things can change)!

Comment: Thanks for your answer DazzaL :), But can you please elaborate on this term "but things can change"?

Comment: @AshokKumar . . . Tables are inherently unordered.  If you want the results in a particular order you have to use the `order by` clause.

Comment: @AshokKumar things can change for example a classic was "select a,b from table group by a,b". quite a few people assumed, as group by tends to order things in memory as part of its processing that it was saef to assume that order by wasn't needed. in the later versions of oracle (10g+) though all this changed which caused lots of code to break. bottom line is if you need an ordered set be sure to specify it ( dont rely on an analytic order by to order the final set).